# function to replace permalink

Tags: facebook, wordpress, wordpress-theming

how can i  add a function  to replace any `the_permalink()` with `@$AWD_facebook→getLoginUrl();` if the plugin that contain this function enabled

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to do, but I think you mean something like this:

```
add_filter('the_permalink','fb_link');
function fb_link($permalink)
{
    global $AWD_facebook;
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    if(is_plugin_active('facebook-awd'))
        return @AWD_facebook->getLoginUrl();
    else
       return $permalink;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Based on Ahwebdev's comment, globalizing the AWD_facebook object within this function should solve your issue.

Comment: not work
i simply want to replace my post link all over the blog with a link that force member to login to my facebook application

Comment: Late, i know, but maybe usefull. This function should work, you just need to globalize the $AWD_facebook object at the top of the function.